# What does Number.register() do?

Tags: python

I have seen the below code in a file called `money.py`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import numbers as _numbers


class Money(Decimal):
    #...... (some class related things here)


_numbers.Number.register(Money)
```

and later in some other code I see:

```
from money import Money
```

I am not able to understand what does `_numbers.Number.register(Money)` do in the `money.py`  file.

Can someone explain the code?

Comment: It says "this is a number": https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register. Example of use in the `numbers` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#adding-more-numeric-abcs

Comment: There is a module named "numbers" that is imported under the name `_numbers`. it provides a class (?) `Number` that has a classmethod / static method `register` where the `class Money` is put into it to be registered.   I doubt this is very helpful though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it's stdlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number

Comment: What is the precise problem you have not understanding the code?

Comment: Your question is a bit weird, because you are asking "what does this function, that is perfectly well documented, in the most accessible place (the stdlib doc), do?". Unless there is a specific part of that documentation you don't understand, the answer would just be "well, read the aforementioned documentation...".

Comment: why to register. whats the use.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register

Comment: Can you explain with some example and use case